Draw a multi-page leftframe (with e.g. \defineframedtext)
In ConTeXt, I want to typeset an "excurses" description with a colored left frame.
It spans about multiple pages and contains footnotes.
I, however, did not get it to work properly.
Here is a MWE that shows the problem:
\defineframedtext[excursusbg][
        frame=off,
        leftframe=on,
        rulethickness=1mm,
        framecolor=blue,
        toffset=0mm,  % there is an offset anyways
]

\definedescription[excursus][
        text={Excursus:\ },
        alternative=top,
        headstyle=bold,
        margin=1cm,
        width=broad,
        before={\startexcursusbg},
        after={\stopexcursusbg},
]

\starttext

\input ward

\startexcursus[title={A Knuth extract}]

\input knuth

\stopexcursus

\input ward

\startexcursus[title={A much longer Knuth extract}]

\input knuth
Sometimes, sentences have footnotes\footnote{Some footnote}.

\input knuth
\input knuth

\stopexcursus

\stoptext

Variant with \defineframedtext
This looks more less like expected for a short excursus like "A Knuth extract":

Ideally, I would like that the leftframe starts exactly at the "Excursus" headline and stops at the last line of the excurses. I tried to adapt toffset for that without success.
It additionally fails to span on multiple pages. The excurses "A much longer Knuth extract" looks quite bad:

Variant with \definetextbackground
I tried another possibility with \definetextbackground. For this, replace the \defineframedtext part with the following snippet:
\definetextbackground[excursusbg] [
      location=text,
      background=color,
      backgroundcolor=lightblue,
      frame=on,
      loffset=10cm,  % seems to have no impact
]

This looks more promising in the multi page case but also fails.
It draws a small extra rectangle in the left margin:

Additionally, it works partly on multi pages, but also colors the footnote text:

Do you have an idea how to achieve the wanted leftframe decoration for an excursus spanning multiple pages and containing footnotes?
For cross references: I already asked the question on the ConTeXt user mailing list (without an answer). I'm using ConTeXt  ver: 2024.09.25 11:53 LMTX  fmt: 2024.9.26
Edit: Aditya gave me the a link to a blog post to solve the problem.
It is much better with that. It, however, does not work with footnotes, either.
Here is an adjusted minimal example:
\definetextbackground[excursusbg][
    location=paragraph,
    mp=mpos:region:leftbar,
    width=broad,
    frame=off,
    framecolor=darkred,
    rulethickness=1mm,
    leftoffset=1cm,
    rightoffset=5mm,
    topoffset=0mm,
    bottomoffset=0mm,
    background=,
]

\startuseMPgraphic{mpos:region:leftbar}
  draw_multi_pars;
  draw_multi_side;
\stopuseMPgraphic

\definedescription[excursus][
        text={Excursus:\ },
        alternative=top,
        headstyle=bold,
        width=broad,
        before={\blank[big]\startexcursusbg},
        after={\stopexcursusbg\blank[big]},
]

\starttext

\input ward

\startexcursus[title={A Knuth extract}]

\input knuth

\stopexcursus

\input ward

\startexcursus[title={A much longer Knuth extract}]

\input knuth
Sometimes, sentences have footnotes\footnote{Some footnote}.

\input knuth
\input knuth

\stopexcursus

\stoptext

It looks like:


framedtext does not break across pages, so you need textbackground. For use location=paragraph to avoid the small rectangles at the end. However, textbackground does not have any loffset option; it is called leftoffset. See this old blog post on how to get the effect that you want:
https://adityam.github.io/context-blog/post/frame-with-solid-left-line-redux/

Nice, that is much closer to my desired effect. However, it also does not work with footnotes. It looks very much like my last example.
